# Carbon Dioxide Specific Heat

Tags: thermodynamics

I am trying to find the specific heat of Carbon Dioxide that is at the temperature of 120 kelvin. In j/kgk

First I would like to know what is the proper formula to use and values for this situation.

Second, I wish to know what would be the ratio between temp and specific heat. Ex. 175 K = 709 j/kgk

I know that Specific Heat is which the temperature point of any sort of material which changes from a different state of matter

Comment: Are you talking about CO2 vapor or solid?   Have you tried Google?

Comment: @Chester Miller it is vapor, I tried google, and nothing shows anything, only thing that remotely helps is https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.engineeringtoolbox.com/amp/carbon-dioxide-d_974.html but that goes only to 175 kelven, doesn’t show anything lower

Comment: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/carbon-dioxide-d_974.html

Comment: Have you plotted a graph to see whether it might be reasonable to extrapolate to the lower temperature?

Comment: How do I do that if I might ask?

Comment: You plot a graph of the heat capacity vs temperature and use your judgment as to whether you believe it can accurately be extrapolated the 50 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the figure below, including an equation for extrapolating to lower temperatures.

[image: CO2 Heat Capacity at constant pressure]

Comment: Thank you for your help, this will contribute for future research